# How to disable TLS certificate validation in lynx?

Tags: ssl, certificates, lynx

I need to access some webpage for which the TLS certificate is invalid,
but `lynx` refuses to connect.

Is there an option similar to `curl -k` for `lynx`?

Here's config file as request

```
.h1 Auxiliary Facilities
.h2 INCLUDE
.ex
.ex
.h2 STARTFILE
.ex
.h2 HELPFILE
.url http://lynx.isc.org/release/breakout/lynx_help/lynx_help_main.html
.ex
HELPFILE:file://localhost/usr/share/doc/lynx-cur/lynx_help/lynx_help_main.html.gz
.h2 DEFAULT_INDEX_FILE
DEFAULT_INDEX_FILE:http://scout.wisc.edu/
.h1 Interaction
.h2 GOTOBUFFER
.h2 JUMP_PROMPT
.h1 Auxiliary Facilities
.h2 JUMPFILE
.ex
.h2 JUMPBUFFER
.h1 Internal Behavior
.h2 SAVE_SPACE
.h2 REUSE_TEMPFILES
.h2 LYNX_HOST_NAME
.h2 LOCALHOST_ALIAS
.ex 2
.h2 LOCAL_DOMAIN
.h1 Session support
.h2 AUTO_SESSION
.h2 SESSION_FILE
.h2 SESSION_LIMIT
.h1 Character Sets
.h2 CHARACTER_SET
.nf
.fi
.url http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1345
CHARACTER_SET:iso-8859-1
.h2 LOCALE_CHARSET
LOCALE_CHARSET:TRUE
.h2 HTML5_CHARSETS
.h2 ASSUME_CHARSET
.h2 ASSUMED_DOC_CHARSET_CHOICE
.h2 DISPLAY_CHARSET_CHOICE
.ex
.ex 4
.h2 ASSUME_LOCAL_CHARSET
.h2 PREPEND_CHARSET_TO_SOURCE
PREPEND_CHARSET_TO_SOURCE:FALSE
.h2 NCR_IN_BOOKMARKS
.h2 FORCE_8BIT_TOUPPER
.h2 OUTGOING_MAIL_CHARSET
.h2 ASSUME_UNREC_CHARSET
.h2 PREFERRED_LANGUAGE
PREFERRED_LANGUAGE:en
.h2 PREFERRED_CHARSET
.url http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2068
.h2 CHARSETS_DIRECTORY
.h2 CHARSET_SWITCH_RULES
.h1 Interaction
.h2 URL_DOMAIN_PREFIXES
.h2 URL_DOMAIN_SUFFIXES
.h2 FORMS_OPTIONS
.h2 PARTIAL
.h2 PARTIAL_THRES
.h2 SHOW_KB_RATE
.h2 SHOW_KB_NAME
.url http://www.romulus2.com/articles/guides/misc/bitsbytes.shtml
.h1 Timeouts
.h2 INFOSECS
.h2 MESSAGESECS
.h2 ALERTSECS
.h2 NO_PAUSE
.h2 DEBUGSECS
.h2 REPLAYSECS
.h1 Appearance
.h2 USE_SELECT_POPUPS
.h2 SHOW_CURSOR
SHOW_CURSOR:TRUE
.h2 UNDERLINE_LINKS
.h2 BOLD_HEADERS
.h2 BOLD_H1
.h2 BOLD_NAME_ANCHORS
.h1 Internal Behavior
.h2 DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE
.h2 DEFAULT_VIRTUAL_MEMORY_SIZE
.h2 SOURCE_CACHE
.h2 SOURCE_CACHE_FOR_ABORTED
.h2 ALWAYS_RESUBMIT_POSTS
.h2 TRIM_INPUT_FIELDS
.h1 HTML Parsing
.h2 NO_ISMAP_IF_USEMAP
.h2 SEEK_FRAG_MAP_IN_CUR
.h2 SEEK_FRAG_AREA_IN_CUR
.h1 CGI scripts
.h2 LOCAL_EXECUTION_LINKS_ALWAYS_ON
.h2 LOCAL_EXECUTION_LINKS_ON_BUT_NOT_REMOTE
LOCAL_EXECUTION_LINKS_ALWAYS_ON:FALSE
LOCAL_EXECUTION_LINKS_ON_BUT_NOT_REMOTE:FALSE
.h2 TRUSTED_EXEC
TRUSTED_EXEC:none
.h2 ALWAYS_TRUSTED_EXEC
ALWAYS_TRUSTED_EXEC:none
.h2 TRUSTED_LYNXCGI
TRUSTED_LYNXCGI:none
.h2 LYNXCGI_ENVIRONMENT
.h2 LYNXCGI_DOCUMENT_ROOT
.h1 Cookies
.h2 FORCE_SSL_COOKIES_SECURE
.h1 Internal Behavior
.h2 MAIL_SYSTEM_ERROR_LOGGING
.h2 CHECKMAIL
.h1 News-groups
.h2 NNTPSERVER
.url http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1738
.h2 LIST_NEWS_NUMBERS
.h2 LIST_NEWS_DATES
.h2 NEWS_CHUNK_SIZE
.h2 NEWS_MAX_CHUNK
.h2 NEWS_POSTING
.h2 LYNX_SIG_FILE
.h1 Bibliographic Protocol (bibp scheme)
.h2 BIBP_GLOBAL_SERVER
.h2 BIBP_BIBHOST
.h1 Interaction
.h2 SCROLLBAR
.h2 SCROLLBAR_ARROW
.h2 USE_MOUSE
.h1 HTML Parsing
.h2 COLLAPSE_BR_TAGS
.h2 TAGSOUP
.h1 Cookies
.h2 SET_COOKIES
.h2 ACCEPT_ALL_COOKIES
.h2 COOKIE_ACCEPT_DOMAINS
.h2 COOKIE_REJECT_DOMAINS
.h2 COOKIE_LOOSE_INVALID_DOMAINS
.h2 COOKIE_STRICT_INVALID_DOMAINS
.h2 COOKIE_QUERY_INVALID_DOMAINS
.h2 MAX_COOKIES_DOMAIN
.h2 MAX_COOKIES_GLOBAL
.h2 MAX_COOKIES_BUFFER
.h2 PERSISTENT_COOKIES
PERSISTENT_COOKIES:FALSE
.h2 COOKIE_FILE
.h2 COOKIE_SAVE_FILE
.h1 Mail-related
.h2 SYSTEM_MAIL
.h2 SYSTEM_MAIL_FLAGS
.ex 2
.ex 2
.ex 2
.ex 2
.ex 2
.url    http://lynx.isc.org/lynx-2.8.1/lynx_w32.zip
.url    ftp://lynx.isc.org/lynx-2.8.1/lynx_w32.zip
.url    http://glob.com.au/sendmail/
.h2 MAIL_ADRS
.h2 USE_FIXED_RECORDS
.h1 Keyboard Input
.h2 VI_KEYS_ALWAYS_ON
.h2 EMACS_KEYS_ALWAYS_ON
.h2 DEFAULT_KEYPAD_MODE
.h2 NUMBER_LINKS_ON_LEFT
.h2 NUMBER_FIELDS_ON_LEFT
.h2 DEFAULT_KEYPAD_MODE_IS_NUMBERS_AS_ARROWS
.h2 CASE_SENSITIVE_ALWAYS_ON
.h1 Auxiliary Facilities
.h2 DEFAULT_BOOKMARK_FILE
.h2 MULTI_BOOKMARK_SUPPORT
.h2 BLOCK_MULTI_BOOKMARKS
.h1 Interaction
.h2 DEFAULT_USER_MODE
.h1 External Programs
.h2 DEFAULT_EDITOR
.h2 SYSTEM_EDITOR
.h3 POSITIONABLE_EDITOR
.h1 Proxy
.h2 HTTP_PROXY
.h2 HTTPS_PROXY
.h2 FTP_PROXY
.h2 GOPHER_PROXY
.h2 NEWSPOST_PROXY
.h2 NEWSREPLY_PROXY
.h2 NEWS_PROXY
.h2 NNTP_PROXY
.h2 SNEWSPOST_PROXY
.h2 SNEWSREPLY_PROXY
.h2 SNEWS_PROXY
.h2 WAIS_PROXY
.h2 FINGER_PROXY
.h2 CSO_PROXY
.ex 15
.h2 NO_PROXY
.ex
.ex
.h1 External Programs
.h2 PRINTER
.h2 DOWNLOADER
.h2 UPLOADER
.ex 3
.ex
.ex
.ex
.ex
.ex
.ex
.ex
.ex 2
.ex
.h1 Interaction
.h2 NO_DOT_FILES
NO_DOT_FILES:FALSE
.h1 Internal Behavior
.h2 NO_FROM_HEADER
.h2 NO_REFERER_HEADER
.h1 Internal Behavior
.h2 NO_FILE_REFERER
.h2 REFERER_WITH_QUERY
.h1 Appearance
.h2 VERBOSE_IMAGES
.h2 MAKE_LINKS_FOR_ALL_IMAGES
.h2 MAKE_PSEUDO_ALTS_FOR_INLINES
.h2 SUBSTITUTE_UNDERSCORES
.h1 Interaction
.h2 QUIT_DEFAULT_YES
.h1 HTML Parsing
.h2 HISTORICAL_COMMENTS
.h2 MINIMAL_COMMENTS
MINIMAL_COMMENTS:TRUE
.h2 SOFT_DQUOTES
.h2 STRIP_DOTDOT_URLS
.h1 Appearance
.h2 ENABLE_SCROLLBACK
.h2 SCAN_FOR_BURIED_NEWS_REFS
.h2 PREPEND_BASE_TO_SOURCE
.h1 External Programs
.h2 GLOBAL_EXTENSION_MAP
.h2 PERSONAL_EXTENSION_MAP
GLOBAL_EXTENSION_MAP:/etc/mime.types
PERSONAL_EXTENSION_MAP:.mime.types
.h2 SUFFIX_ORDER
.h2 SUFFIX
.ex
.ex
.ex
.ex
.ex 29
SUFFIX:.tgz:application/octet-stream
SUFFIX:.deb:application/octet-stream
.h2 XLOADIMAGE_COMMAND
.h2 VIEWER
.ex 7
.h2 GLOBAL_MAILCAP
.h2 PERSONAL_MAILCAP
.url http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1524
GLOBAL_MAILCAP:/etc/mailcap
PERSONAL_MAILCAP:.mailcap
.h2 PREFERRED_MEDIA_TYPES
.h2 PREFERRED_ENCODING
.h1 Keyboard Input
.h2 KEYBOARD_LAYOUT
.h2 KEYMAP
.nf
.fi
.nf
.fi
.nf
.fi
.nf
.fi
.nf
.fi
.nf
.fi
.nf
.fi
.h1 External Programs
.h2 CSWING_PATH
.h1 Internal Behavior
.h2 AUTO_UNCACHE_DIRLISTS
.h1 Appearance
.h2 LIST_FORMAT
.nf
.fi
.ex
.ex
.ex
.h1 External Programs
.h2 DIRED_MENU
.nf
.fi
.h1 Internal Behavior
.h2 NONRESTARTING_SIGWINCH
.h2 NO_FORCED_CORE_DUMP
.h1 Appearance
.h2 COLOR
.nf
.fi
COLOR:6:brightred:black
.h2 COLOR_STYLE
.h2 NESTED_TABLES
.h2 ASSUMED_COLOR
.h2 DEFAULT_COLORS
.h1 External Programs
.h2 EXTERNAL
.h2 EXTERNAL_MENU
.ex 1
.h1 Internal Behavior
.h2 RULE
.h2 RULESFILE
.ex 5
.h1 Appearance
.h2 PRETTYSRC
.h2 PRETTYSRC_SPEC
.nf
.fi
.ex
.ex
.ex
.h2 HTMLSRC_ATTRNAME_XFORM
.h2 HTMLSRC_TAGNAME_XFORM
.h2 PRETTYSRC_VIEW_NO_ANCHOR_NUMBERING
.h1 HTML Parsing
.h2 FORCE_EMPTY_HREFLESS_A
.h2 HIDDEN_LINK_MARKER
.h2 XHTML_PARSING
.h1 Appearance
.h2 JUSTIFY
.h2 JUSTIFY_MAX_VOID_PERCENT
.h1 Interaction
.h2 TEXTFIELDS_NEED_ACTIVATION
.h2 LEFTARROW_IN_TEXTFIELD_PROMPT
.h1 Timeouts
.h2 CONNECT_TIMEOUT
.h2 READ_TIMEOUT
.h1 Internal Behavior
.h2 FTP_PASSIVE
.h2 ENABLE_LYNXRC
.nf
.fi
.h1 External Programs
.h2 BZIP2_PATH
.h2 CHMOD_PATH
.h2 COMPRESS_PATH
.h2 COPY_PATH
.h2 GZIP_PATH
.h2 INFLATE_PATH
.h2 INSTALL_PATH
.h2 MKDIR_PATH
.h2 MV_PATH
.h2 RLOGIN_PATH
.h2 RMDIR_PATH
.h2 RM_PATH
.h2 SETFONT_PATH
.h2 TAR_PATH
.h2 TELNET_PATH
.h2 TN3270_PATH
.h2 TOUCH_PATH
.h2 UNCOMPRESS_PATH
.h2 UNZIP_PATH
.h2 UUDECODE_PATH
.h2 ZCAT_PATH
.h2 ZIP_PATH
.h1 Interaction
.h2 FORCE_SSL_PROMPT
.h2 FORCE_COOKIE_PROMPT
.h2 SSL_CERT_FILE
SSL_CERT_FILE:/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
.h1 Appearance
.h2 SCREEN_SIZE
.h2 NO_MARGINS
.h2 NO_TITLE
.h1 External Programs
.h2 SYSLOG_REQUESTED_URLS
SYSLOG_REQUESTED_URLS:FALSE
.h2 SYSLOG_TEXT
.h1 Internal Behavior
.h2 BROKEN_FTP_RETR
.h2 BROKEN_FTP_EPSV
.h1 Appearance
.h2 FTP_FORMAT
.h1 Internal Behavior
.h2 STATUS_BUFFER_SIZE
.h2 MAX_URI_SIZE
.h1 Appearance
.h2 UNIQUE_URLS
.h1 Character Sets
.h2 MESSAGE_LANGUAGE
.h2 CONV_JISX0201KANA
.h1 External Programs
.h2 WAIT_VIEWER_TERMINATION
.h1 Mail-related
.h2 BLAT_MAIL
.url http://www.blat.net
.h2 ALT_BLAT_MAIL
.url http://www.piedey.co.jp/blatj/
.h1 Internal Behavior
.h2 TRACK_INTERNAL_LINKS
EXTERNAL:ftp:w3m %s:TRUE
EXTERNAL:file:w3m %s:TRUE
EXTERNAL:http:w3m %s:TRUE
EXTERNAL:http:wget %s:TRUE
EXTERNAL:http:wget -r %s:TRUE
EXTERNAL:ftp:x-www-browser %s:TRUE
EXTERNAL:file:x-www-browser %s:TRUE
EXTERNAL:http:x-www-browser %s:TRUE
INCLUDE:/etc/lynx-cur/local.cfg
INCLUDE:~/.lynx/colors:COLOR
INCLUDE:~/.lynx/keymap:KEYMAP
INCLUDE:~/.lynx/viewers:VIEWER
INCLUDE:~/.lynx/external:EXTERNAL
```

Complete file (with comments) can be found [here](https://clbin.com/hxB4N)

Answer (score 0):

Is lynx producing one of the following errors?

> SSL error:host(...)...-Continue? (n)

If so, simply enter `y`.

> Alert!: Unable to make secure connection to remote host.

File `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` might be missing a certificate, e.g., a self-signed certificate.

(Can you supply the actual URL?)

Comment: The error is : Alert!: Unable to make secure connection to remote host.

Comment: What's in your config file? Use `cat /usr/local/lib/lynx.cfg`. If that doesn't work, then use `whereis lynx` to find the directory, e.g., `/etc/lynx`, followed by `cat /etc/lynx/lynx.cfg`

Comment: config file has been added to question as requested.